# Internal symmetries in abelian or non abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, group-extensions, central-extensions

so I've been studying the centrally extended Galilei group, by restricting to 1D translation, the group becomes abelian and that means that all the irreps of the groups are of dimension 1. A consequence of this statement is that this version of the group does not have any internal symmetries (well it has but they all act trivially on the Hilbert space).

So the way I understood it is that the internal structure of the group should come from the multiplicities (if the multiplicities of the regular representation are all of dimension 1, there's no internal structure and if they have higher dimensions then there's is).

This was the conclusion of a discussion I had with a professor, but I have tried to research these information and I couldn't find anything really clear. Even the definition of the concept of internal symmetries isn't clear at this point. Can someone help me with some references and some course notes, that'd be great.

Comment: Are "internal symmetries" maybe "inner automorphisms"? It is true that abelian groups do not have non-trivial inner automorphisms, but seeing that from their representation theory is massive overkill.

Comment: In the context of my master's thesis, we're studying the invariant algebra, so I'm not sure that the considered transformations that would leave the operators invariant would qualify as inner automorphisms or not to be honest.

Comment: The thing is that you are not providing any definition of what you call "internal symmetries", and that is not a standard mathematical term. So you are going to need to give more details to get an answer. The closest thing I could think of to what "internal symmetries" may be are inner automorphisms, and they happen to be trivial for abelian groups, so that seemed to fit, but in the end it is up to you to provide context for your question.